# No newline after div?

Tags: html, css-float, newline

Is there a way to not have a newline inserted before a `div` without using `float: left` on the previous element?

Maybe some tag on the `div` that will just put it to the right?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is no *newline*, just the `div` is a block element.

You can make the `div` inline by adding `display: inline`, which may be what you want.

Comment: although you might just want to use a span.

Answer (score 40):

Have you considered using `span` instead of `div`? It is the in-line version of `div`.

Answer (score 22):

```
<div style="display: inline">Is this what you meant?</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Quoting Mr Initial Man from [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?79156-No-line-break-after-lt-div-gt&p=434049#post434049):

> Instead of this:
>
> ```
> <div id="Top" class="info"></div><a href="#" class="a_info"></a>
> ```
>
> Use this:
>
> ```
> <span id="Top" class="info"></span><a href="#" class="a_info"></a>
> ```
>
> Also, you could use this:
>
> ```
> <div id="Top" class="info"><a href="#" class="a_info"></a></div>
> ```

And [gostbustaz](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?79156-No-line-break-after-lt-div-gt&p=440528#post440528):

> If you absoultely must use a `<div>`,
>   you can set
>
> ```
> div {
>     display: inline;
> }
> ```
>
> in your stylesheet.
>
> Of course, that essentially makes the
>   `<div>` a `<span>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use span instead of div. Since span is inline element while div is the block element. So div is always going to add into the new line as it covers the entire width while span doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

This works like magic, use it in the CSS file on the div you want to have on the new line:

```
.div_class {
    clear: left;
}
```

Or declare it in the html:

```
<div style="clear: left">
     <!-- Content... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works the best, in my case, I tried it all

```
.div_class {
    clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
div.noWrap {
    display: inline;
    }
```